# Set email with non-Gmail domain as primary in Google Developers Console

Tags: google-oauth

I want to use Google as OAuth provider for my web site. So I created a new project in Google Developers Console. There under "Consent screen" I wanted to set the email address my users can see when logging in to my company's non-Gmail address.

However, since this is a drop-down box I can only choose from one of the associated accounts, set in the project's permissions. My problem is that I need to set an email address that does not belong to Google, nor do I have a Google Apps account.

So my question is: Can I set a non-Gmail email address in a Google project, even if that domain is not in Google Apps?

Comment: There must be a way. If you go to the login page of StackOverflow (in a different browser) and click ["Log in using Google"](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=717762328687-p17pldm5fteklla3nplbss3ai9slta0a.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=profile+email&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fstackauth.com%2fauth%2foauth2%2fgoogle), the "programmer" that requests your permission has a domain e-mail (team@stackoverflow.com).

Comment: stackoverflow.com is using google apps though this is possible with non-gmail email address. please see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to register an account at google developer with your non-gmail address first. And then go to Permissions in the Google Developers Console, add a Member with the non-gmail account as owner. After that you will be able to select the non-gmail email address in Consent screen.