# Adding custom domain member as owner in project - GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add my client as owner on my Google Cloud Console Project, but I am getting the following error: `An email address does not belong to an active account`

[image]

Here I create Google account for him(related to his custom domain), but I also found difficulties in granting him as  the owner of the project.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to register an account at google developer with your non-gmail address first. And then go to Permissions in the Google Developers Console, add a Member with the non-gmail account as owner. After that you will be able to select the non-gmail email address in Consent screen [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774334/861607)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a user to your project using the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/home/dashboard?). When you add a user to your Google Compute Engine project, it gives the user some amount of access to Google Compute Engine resources in that project, determined by the roles such as viewer, editor, or owner. For example, if you add a user as an owner, they will be able to add and modify Google Compute Engine resources in the project, connect to the project's instances using SSH, and change the project's membership.

To add or delete users, or to change their permissions:

1. Go to the **Permissions** page in the console.
2. To add a new team member, click the **Add Member** button.
3. To delete a team member, check the box next to their account and click Remove.
4. To change a user's permissions, select a different role in the **Permission** column.

You can choose from these three user roles:

- **Can View** - provide READ access
- **Can Edit** - provides "Can View" access
- **Is Owner** - provides "Can Edit" access

For more information check [Managing your project's users](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/access), and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316238/deployment-to-google-s-compute-engine-fails-error-retrieving-the-app-engine-ser).

Comment: are you coping and pasting docs! Officail docs its ok but in my case is not working and I am looking for solution or workaround ...